How to convert Flux<Mono<String>> to List<String>
have written reactive application using springboot-3.x,webflux and need to convert Flux<Mono<String>> to List<String> 

First flatten the Flux<Mono<String>> to Flux<String>, then collect to Mono<List<String>>, then get its value:
Flux<Mono<String>> flux = ...
List<String> list = flux.flatMap(Function.identity()) // Flux<String>
        .collectList()                                // Mono<List<String>>
        .block();


I think you can improve your answer by warning user that using block(); can have severe implication (risk of failure or severe performance impact)
